# PyGithub BadCredentialsException when calling Github.get_organization()

Tags: python, git, github, github-api

I'm using [PyGithub v1.25](http://jacquev6.github.io/PyGithub/v1/introduction.html) to create a little webapp where members of my organization can create private repositories in our github organization.  Right now, I'm getting a `BadCredentialsException` when trying to call the `get_organization()` method of the [`Github` base class](http://jacquev6.github.io/PyGithub/v1/github.html).

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
from github import Github                                                                

import settings                                                                  


GIT_OBJECT = Github(login_or_token=settings.AUTH_TOKEN)                          
ORG_OBJECT = GIT_OBJECT.get_organization('My-Organization-Name')
```

The auth token I am using was generated from my github user account, which has sufficient privileges to create private repositories in this organization when using the github web interface.  I created the token with ["user", "repo", and "admin:org" scopes](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) selected.  I am getting an error at the creation of `ORG_OBJECT`.

The stack trace:

```
File "/local/path/to/my/code/github_console/console/org_manage.py", line 10, in <module>
  ORG_OBJECT = GIT_OBJECT.get_organization(‘My-Organization-Name’)
File "/local/path/to/my/code/github_console/lib/github/MainClass.py", line 187, in get_organization
  "/orgs/" + login
File "/local/path/to/my/code/github_console/lib/github/Requester.py", line 169, in requestJsonAndCheck
  return self.__check(*self.requestJson(verb, url, parameters, headers, input, cnx))
File "/local/path/to/my/code/github_console/lib/github/Requester.py", line 177, in __check
  raise self.__createException(status, responseHeaders, output)
BadCredentialsException: 401 {u'documentation_url': u'https://developer.github.com/v3', u'message': u'Bad credentials'}
```

If anyone who has used either PyGithub or the github API before (or someone who is better than me at reading docs) has any insights, I appreciate the help!

Here's [the PyGithub source code](https://github.com/jacquev6/PyGithub/blob/b64b0d6942bb27095bd035b8c0db10ca35448be3/github/MainClass.py#L178), in case anyone wants a look at that.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a curl request in the terminal? Doing that would be helpful because it would tell you if this is a problem in the library or with how you're using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh!

Apparently, the above displayed code works great, and I just effed up importing local settings into my settings module, so a dummy `AUTH_TOKEN` was being used, and of course, resulting in a `BadCredentialsException`.

On the plus side, I guess the above is a demonstration of correct PyGithub usage.

Comment: Where does the auth token come from? Is it from registering a new GitHub app for my organization?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to check your personal access token/API Key on github and ensure it hasn't expired.

This just happened to me today.